# On simplicity of $q$ stable coherent systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\underline {Background}$ : A coherent system on a polarized projective variety $(X, L)$ over $\mathbb C$ is a pair $(E,V)$, where $E$ is a $d$ dimensional coherent sheaf on $X$ and $V \subset H^0(E)$ a subspace. A morphism of coherent systems $f : (E,V) \to (E',V')$ is a morphism of coherent sheaves $f :E \to E'$ such that $f(V) \subset V'$.

Let $q \in \mathbb Q[t]$ be fixed  with positive leading coefficient. Then a coherent system $(E,V)$ is called $q$-stable if $E$ is pure  and for any coherent subsheaf $F \subset E$ we have $\mathcal P^q_{(F,V')} < \mathcal P^q_{(E,V)}$ with $V' = V \cap H^0(F)$ ,
where $\mathcal P^q_{(E,V)}(t) := \frac {dimV}{\alpha_d(E)}.q(t) + \mathcal P_E(t)$. [Here $\mathcal P_E$ is the reduced Hilbert polynomial of $E$ and $\alpha_d(E)$ is the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of $E$  expressed as sum of $\frac {m^i}{i!}$]

At this point  what **I want to prove** is :  $q$ stability of $(E,V)$ implies $(E,V)$ is simple (i.e letting $A =(E,V)$,  $End(A) \cong \mathbb C$)

$\underline { Attempts}$: $(1)$ My strategy was that $(E,V)$ is $q$ stable $ \implies E$ is stable $ \implies$ $E$ is simple $\implies$ $A =(E,V)$ is simple. I don't have any problem showing the last two implications, but I am unable to show the first implication.[At this point I don't think that the first implication is always true,but I don't have a concrete counterexample at hand to disprove that implication and if it's not true then it would be nice to know for which $q$ the first implication stands]

$(2)$ Another approach : If we start with $f \in  End (A) $ which is not zero and further more if we assume that $f$ is not an isomorphism then we have the following short exact sequence $ 0 \to F \to E \to G \to 0$, where, $F =kerf, G =Imf$.

I also hope that we have a S.E.S of vector spaces $ 0 \to V' \to  V \to V'' \to 0$,where, $V' = H^0(kerf) \cap V, V'' =H^0(Imf) \cap V$.

Since, $(E,V)$ is $q$ - stable we have $\mathcal P^q_{(F,V')}(t) < \mathcal P^q_{(E,V)}(t),  \mathcal P^q_{(G,V'')}(t) < \mathcal P^q_{(E,V)}(t)$ for $t >>0$.From where, we have $\mathcal P^q_{(E,V)}(t) = \frac {dimV}{\alpha_d(E)}.q(t) + \mathcal P_E(t) =\frac{\alpha_d(F).\mathcal P^q_{(F,V')}(t) + \alpha_d(G).\mathcal P^q_{(G,V'')}(t)}{\alpha_d(F). + \alpha_d(G).}< \mathcal P^q_{(E,V)}(t)$ for $t >>0$, which is a contradiction.That means any nonzero such $f$ must be an isomorphism.

Now if we take $ \beta  $  to be an eigen value of the induced map $f' :H^0(E \otimes L^t) \to H^0(E \otimes L^t)$(for some $t >>0$),then $F :=f - \beta .I_d \in End(A)$. But since the induced map $ F' : H^0(E \otimes L^t) \to H^0(E \otimes L^t)$ is not an isomorphism ,so $F$ can't be an isomorphism and hence $F=0$ and we are through.

Does any of the two approaches constitute a valid proof of the desired statement?Can somebody give me a reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: spacing after dash in "$q$-stable" is non-standard typing. Also you're using italics at many places instead of roman (dim, End, Im...).

Comment: ... and without dash it looks like you have $q$ systems (the number of systems is $q$).